# Run sails console on a different port then sails lift

Tags: console, port, sails.js

How do I run sails console and sails lift at the same time?

From what I have read (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/lib/app) I need to use `sails.load` instead of `sails.lift`. I do not have the slightest idea where I need to put that and how it connects with sails console. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sails lift` and `sails console` natively handle some parameters. So you can use:

- `sails lift` to run your app on the default port (1337 if you don't modify your config)
- `sails console --port 1338` in an other tab/window to run the console on another port

Comment: This works better.  Was this on the website or the github some place?  I was searching for this for a while.  Just curious.  Thanks!

Comment: You can read this [on the docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-lift) (you've got to know it to find it...)

Comment: I don't know how I missed that.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Try with

```
sails lift --port 8080
```

That worked out for me.

Answer (score 3):

open  **config/env/production.js**  and scroll down, find 
 **//port 80**  end then, uncomment it
[image: unkoment it]

Answer (score 2):

Add this line under config/locale.js. now run the application again now your application will run over port 80 and if you want to run the app on some other port, you need to replace 80 with that port number.

```
module.exports{
port: process.env.PORT || 80,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

find **//port: 80** end then, uncomment it in **config/env/production.js** and provide any port you want

after that run following command

> NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js  -- --prod

it will work perfectly but if you want **-i max** than.

> NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js --name "myapp" -i max -- --prod

in the above command if you  fase any issue regarding **grunt** than open **tasks/register/prod.js** and comment below lines

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('prod', [
    // 'polyfill:prod', //« Remove this to skip transpilation in production (not recommended)
    // 'compileAssets',
    // 'babel',         //« Remove this to skip transpilation in production (not recommended)
    // 'concat',
    // 'uglify',
    // 'cssmin',
    // 'sails-linker:prodJs',
    // 'sails-linker:prodStyles',
    // 'sails-linker:clientSideTemplates',
  ]);

};
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solution without `sails.load` since I never use it. Edit your `config/bootstrap.js` to like this:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {

  if(process.argv[2]){
    var port = parseInt(process.argv[2]);
    sails.config.port = port;
  }

  cb();
};
```

then lift your app by `node app.js 1234` to make it run on port 1234.

But if you still want to use `sails.lift`, change `process.argv[2]` to `process.argv[3]`. Basically it catch any arguments when you starting application, and change `sails.config.port` based on your arguments.

Comment: Or you can just set the port value in the regular config file.